# Edit existing .htaccess to work with subdirectories too

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory

I have an existing .htaccess file that looks like this:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^posts/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?content=blog&postid=$1&kwd=$2
RewriteRule ^aposts/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?content=autopost&postid=$1&kwd=$2
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?content=category&cat=$1&otext=$2
RewriteRule ^content/(.*).html$ index.php?content=$1
RewriteRule ^searching/(.*).html$ index.php?content=search&k=$1
RewriteRule ^related/(.*).html$ index.php?content=related&k=$1
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?content=blog&postid=$1&kwd=$2
RewriteRule ^posts$ index.php?content=blog
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots.php [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

This works how it was initailly intended for root domain address visitors.

What I want now is to add the functionality of accepting directories too, for example:

```
example.com/directory1
```

or

```
example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4
```

but I want it to keep the same functionality as it currently does.

I hope that makes sense, but feel free to ask for clarification.

Thanks for anyhelp with this.

Comment: Where should those new urls redirect to? Would example.com/directory1/posts/x/y also go to `index.php?content=blog&postid=x&kwd=y`?

Comment: Yes, but it would keep the example.com/directory1/posts/x/y in the address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^posts/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?content=blog&postid=$1&kwd=$2
```

This rule of yours always only matches when the URI starts with "posts".

To allow one or more subdirectories before such a rule, you want to look for one or more characters followed by a `/` before "posts":

`(.+/)?` this selects "one or more of any characters, followed by a `/`", zero or one times. Since "any character" also includes a slash this counts for any amount of subdirectories, as long as after the last slash the "posts" appears.

Since an extra set of parentheses is introduced, you will need to access `$2` and `$3` now.

So your rule becomes:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?posts/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?content=blog&postid=$2&kwd=$3
```

You can apply this to each of your rules.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it.

Regarding the extra set of parentheses, any line refering to $1, becomes $2, $2 to $3 etc., but what about he lines without, eg:

>`RewriteRule ^posts$ index.php?content=blog`
>`RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]`
>`RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots.php [L]`
>`ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`

Thanks.

Comment: They don't use variables in the first place, so no need to change anything in the redirect target. You can safely add parentheses without using the variables, just know that if you _do_ use them you have to match the number.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer and the level of detail supplied, it's really appreciated.

Comment: Although it works as I requested, I've found it isn't quite doing what I wanted it to do.  For example, if I enter the domain example.com/sub1/sub2/posts/x/y.html, I want it to use the index.php file from the root folder but still show example.com/sub1/sub2/posts/x/y.html in the address bar.  Is that achievable?

Comment: Which part of that doesn't it do?

Comment: Some further checks have revealed that the rules themselves work, sorry for doubting you.  I may need to add another rule however so that when I go to any subdirectory it uses the root index.php file, so for example, going to example.com/sub1/sub2/sub3 uses the root index.php file but still shows example.com/sub1/sub2/sub3 in the address bar.  I've tried various things, so any pointers how to achieve that appreciated too.  Thank you.

Comment: Couldn't get this part to work so asked question.  It got answered by the amazing Jon Lin here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26024837/1061571  Big thank you to @isogram too