# All subdirectories to use root index.php file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

My existing .htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?posts/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?content=blog&postid=$2&kwd=$3
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?aposts/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?content=autopost&postid=$2&kwd=$3
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?category/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?content=category&cat=$2&otext=$3
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?content/(.*).html$ index.php?content=$2
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?searching/(.*).html$ index.php?content=search&k=$2
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?related/(.*).html$ index.php?content=related&k=$2
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?blog/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?content=blog&postid=$2&kwd=$3
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?posts$ index.php?content=blog
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?robots\.txt$ robots.php [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

I would like to add the ability for all subdirectories to use the root index.php file.  For example, if a visitor goes to the root directory:

```
example.com
```

They get served the root index.php file.

I want it so that if anybody goes to any other subdirectories eg:

```
example.com/sub1
example.com/sub1/sub2/sub3/etc..
```

They get served the index.php file from the root directory BUT the browser address bar still shows the subdirectories, eg:

```
example.com/sub1
example.com/sub1/sub2/sub3/etc..
```

Being shown how to add exceptions to this rule would be great too.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right under `RewriteBase /` add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond $1 !^index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php [L]
```

To add exceptions, just add more `RewriteCond` lines. For example, to make it so `/foo/` doesn't get routed to index.php, add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond $1 !^foo/
RewriteCond $1 !^index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you Jon, whilst researching the answer myself I came across just how much you contribute and help others.

I've just tried adding the code and it seems to be stopping my pages loading fully for some reason.  Will the code supplied only work for subdirectories without a specified file or does it redirect all?

For exmaple: domain.com/sub1/sub2 should be redirected, but domain.com/sub1/sub2/index.html or domain.com/sub1/sub2/index.php shouldn't.  I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much.  I could spend days chatting through with you some of the amswers you have given here to previous problems.  In fact one of your previous answers has already piqued my interest and I plan on looking into it further.